# How to create capturing groups with regex re.compile?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, regex-group, regex-greedy

Can successful find the string, but can't split the match object into the right groups

The full string is the following:

```
 Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello
```

(all on one line). What I'm trying to do is find this line in the file (which works), but then when I want to add to the dict, I only want to add the part "Technology Libraries" and not everything else. I wanted to use .group() and specify which group but only the Techlibhellohellohello appears to pop up as a group(1) and no other comes up. Also, there is leading white spaces before Technology Libraries

## object to match

`is_startline_1      = re.compile(r"    Technology libraries: (.*)$")`

## line that matches

`startline1_match                  = is_startline_1.match(line)`

## adding to dict

```
bookmark_dict['context']        = startline1_match.group(1)
```

The Desired output is for .groups(1) or .groups(2) to contain "Technology Libraries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we might just want to wrap the first part with a capturing group:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(Technology libraries: )(.*)$"

test_str = "Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello"

subst = "\\1\\n\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

This JavaScript demo shows how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /(Technology libraries: )(.*)$/gm;
const str = `Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello`;
const subst = `\n$1\n$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6QFdM3/1).

```
 (Technology libraries: )(.*)
```

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

---

If you wish to remove the `:` and white spaces, you can simply add a middle capturing group that does so:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIhXlj/1)

```
(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)
```

[image]

#### Python Code

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)"

test_str = ("Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello\n"
    "Technology libraries:     Techlibhellohellohello")

subst = "\\1\\n\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)/gm;
const str = `Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello
Technology libraries:     Techlibhellohellohello`;
const subst = `\n$1\n$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

---

If you like to capture the spaces before "Technology libraries", you can simply add them to a capturing group:

```
^(\s+)(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dFYtDX/1)

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(\s+)(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)$"

test_str = ("    Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello\n"
    "       Technology libraries:     Techlibhellohellohello")

subst = "\\2\\n\\4"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(\s+)(Technology libraries)(:\s+)(.*)$/gm;
const str = `    Technology libraries: Techlibhellohellohello
       Technology libraries:     Techlibhellohellohello`;
const subst = `$2\n$4`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Hello Emma, will this handle the leading white spaces before technology libraries?

Comment: hello yes I do! I’ll be trying your solution later and be able to see if it works for me :)

Comment: Hey Emma, I believe you misunderstood the whitespaces before technology, The file has a line where it has 5 "spaces" then the word Technology libraries comes right after. You have a very detailed solution and I thank you for that, I'm trying to apply it now.

Comment: Emma, you went above and beyond and I thank you for that. I was looking at what you did, and basically, all I had to do was to put my line that has my re.compile and change it like this:                                         is_startline_1      = re.compile(r"    (Technology libraries): (.*)$")